# How to consume an ASP.NET Web Service in Windows Console App (VS2008)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asmx

I have in the past coded up Windows Form or Console apps in Visual Studio (2005 and earlier), and the IDE has facilitated linking up with a web service.  Now I am building an application that needs to consume a web service, but when I right-click on the project (or References), I do not see a "Add Web Reference" context menu item (for WinForm or Console app).  There IS one if I right-click on a Web Application project, but this doesn't help me, as the application I am building MUST be a console app.  This was not the behavior in VS2005.  The [MSDN page that describes the process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx.aspx) for .NET 3.5 does not make a distinction; i.e. does not acknowledge a difference.

I am not making this up, and it is not an optical illusion.  Here's are the two context menus, side by side:

[Comparison context menus in VS2008 for Web Service. http://blog.clarkmichael.com/content/binary/VS2008_ProjContextMenu.jpg](http://blog.clarkmichael.com/content/binary/VS2008_ProjContextMenu.jpg)

Anybody have an idea how to do what I want?  I suspect that it is possible to do via some hand-coding, even if the IDE isn't going to help out, but I'm unsure where to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With VS2008 MS is focused on WCF-Services. You can select a Webservice Reference by clicking "Add Service Reference..." and on the following dialog clicking the "Advanced..." button. In the following dialog you can choose to add a Web Service Reference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Bacon saving time.  And leave it to Microsoft to hide something that used to exist in a  highly visible location, and without comment in the documentation, shove it into an obscure location 2 levels deeper in the IDE!  I can imagine some design wanker saying to himself, "Well, nobody cares about this anymore, so we'll just hide it where the sun doesn't shine."  Did someone take a survey to decide this?  He probably just asked his liberal-arts degreed girlfriend, and when she said "Huh?" he ticked the box marked "Asked the users?"

Comment: It's obscure because it's almost obsolete. ASMX web services are a legacy technology which is now in maintenance mode. Why encourage people to use technology that's not being actively developed?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, there's lots of legacy stuff out there, and people still need to access it.  I am not asking for encouragement, I am asking for them to NOT make it hard to do what needs to be done by hiding things.  But they're not listening, so it doesn't matter what I ask.  Sigh.  Do you know that I still have to maintain crap written in VB5, for crying out loud?  And just recently it became necessary for that VB5 crap to access a freaking Web Service?  OMG.  What next? Pretty soon it will be a DOS 6 app wanting to be interfaced with Amazon EC2.  That would be resume dispersion time.

Comment: You can easily create a WCF client in .NET and expose it via COM. Your VB5 app will just see COM, but you'll be writing modern WCF.

Comment: And in fact that is what I did -- except that it was a web service client because the service wasn't WCF. Similar task, same method. It was kind of fun, actually! Thanks for the comeback, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'Add Service Reference' option.